# Using NSProgress to find download speed and time remaining

Tags: ios, macos, ios7, osx-mavericks, nsprogress

According to the [documentation for `NSProgress`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSProgress_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSProgress/localizedAdditionalDescription) I see that `-[NSProgress localizedAdditionalDescription]` can report download speed and time remaining, e.g.:

> 1.61 GB of 3.22 GB (2 KB/sec) — 2 minutes remaining

However, I'm not able to get those details when I associate an `NSProgress` to a `NSURLSessionDownloadTask`. Here's my code:

**Downloader.h**

```
@interface Downloader : NSObject
@property NSProgress *overallProgress;
-(void)startDownload;
@end
```

**Downloader.m**

```
- (void)startDownload {

    self.overallProgress = [NSProgress progressWithTotalUnitCount:100];

    [self.overallProgress setKind:NSProgressKindFile];
    [self.overallProgress setUserInfoObject:NSProgressFileOperationKindKey forKey:NSProgressFileOperationKindDownloading];


    [self.overallProgress becomeCurrentWithPendingUnitCount:100];
    [self work1];
    [self.overallProgress resignCurrent];
}

- (void)work1 {

    NSProgress *firstTaskProgress = [NSProgress progressWithTotalUnitCount:1];
    [firstTaskProgress setKind:NSProgressKindFile];
    [firstTaskProgress setUserInfoObject:NSProgressFileOperationKindKey forKey:NSProgressFileOperationKindDownloading];

    NSURL *downloadURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/200MB.zip"];
    NSURL *destinationDirectory = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] firstObject];
    NSURL *destinationURL = [destinationDirectory URLByAppendingPathComponent:[downloadURL lastPathComponent]];

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
    NSURLSessionDownloadTask *fileDownloadTask =
    [session downloadTaskWithURL:downloadURL
               completionHandler:^(NSURL *location, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error){

                   [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:destinationURL error:NULL];

                   [[NSFileManager defaultManager] moveItemAtURL:location toURL:destinationURL error:nil];

                   [firstTaskProgress setCompletedUnitCount:1];
               }];

    [fileDownloadTask resume];
}
```

**DownloadObserver.m**

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    downloader = [Downloader new];

    [downloader addObserver:self
                 forKeyPath:@"overallProgress.fractionCompleted"
                    options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                    context:NULL];

    [downloader startDownload];

}

-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    NSLog(@"%@", [downloader.overallProgress localizedAdditionalDescription]);
}
```

This only prints out:

> 0 of 100
>
> Zero KB of 100 bytes

How can I get `localizedAdditionalDescription` to print the download speed and time remaining?

Comment: Marc solved a similar question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/370641/calculating-connection-download-speed

Comment: No, my question is about how to get `NSProgress` to do those calculations for you.

Comment: OK... what about this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19666883/update-uiprogressview-from-nsprogress

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First of all, `totalUnitCount` should correspond to the size of a file in bytes. During download process we change `completedUnitCount` which reflects on `localizedAdditionalDescription`. `NSProgressKindFile` is a hint to format those values as file size.

To set progress properly we need to use `NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate` methods instead of block handler. In -`URLSession: downloadTask: didWriteData: totalBytesWritten: totalBytesExpectedToWrite:` we have all information to initiate (totalBytesExpectedToWrite) and update (totalBytesWritten) progress.

```
static void *myContext = &myContext;

- (void)download {
    NSURL *downloadURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/10MB.zip"];
    NSURLSession *session =
    [NSURLSession
     sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]
     delegate:self
     delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

    [[session downloadTaskWithURL:downloadURL] resume];
}

#pragma mark - url session download delegate

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session
      downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask
      didWriteData:(int64_t)bytesWritten
 totalBytesWritten:(int64_t)totalBytesWritten
totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToWrite
{
    if (!_progress) {
        _progress = [NSProgress progressWithTotalUnitCount:totalBytesExpectedToWrite];
        _progress.kind = NSProgressKindFile;
        [_progress addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"fractionCompleted" options:0 context:myContext];
    }

    _progress.completedUnitCount = totalBytesWritten;
    //[_overallProgress setUserInfoObject:@1024 forKey:NSProgressEstimatedTimeRemainingKey];
}

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session 
      downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask
didFinishDownloadingToURL:(NSURL *)location
{
    [_progress removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"fractionCompleted"];
    _progress = nil;
    NSLog(@"finished: %@", location);
}

-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                     ofObject:(id)object
                       change:(NSDictionary *)change
                      context:(void *)context
{
    if (context == myContext) {
        self.label.text = [_progress localizedAdditionalDescription];
    }
    else {
        [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object change:change context:context];
    }
}
```

In fact, `NSProgress` doesn't do any calculations. It just formats localized description according to `userInfo` and other class properties. See [Constants](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSProgress_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013490-CH1-DontLinkElementID_2) section in documentation. You can play with these values and compare localized description outputs.

If you want to display remaining download time you can use `NSProgressEstimatedTimeRemainingKey`. Bad news is that you need to calculate remaining time manually. Reference: [How to estimate download time remaining (accurately)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779600/how-to-estimate-download-time-remaining-accurately)

I tried to set `NSProgressThroughputKey` which indicates the speed of data processing in bytes per second. I expected that `NSProgress` would calculate remaining time, but it didn't happen.

See also [AFNetworking sources](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/AFURLSessionManager.m): `AFURLSessionManagerTaskDelegate` uses instances of `NSProgress` for upload and download tasks.

Comment: Thanks. So you have to make those calculations *yourself*! So far, `NSProgress` is just a glorified encapsulator for progress data... I guess `NSProgress` is useful when you chain several of them together..?

Comment: Yes, this is a prominent feature

Comment: @Mojo66: the question was answered _thoroughly_.