# Stuck while Updating Progress bar in iPad table view

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios6, ios-simulator

Hi I am Updating ProgressBar by Calling Below method at each iteration while updating to UI, Progress bar stucks meanwhile I am getting correct value of propagation.

```
-(void)updateProgressForTestApple:(OSVersion)version withValue:(float)val{
switch (module) {
    case myModule:
    {
        [self.myCustomCell.progressView setProgress:val animated:YES];
        NSLog(@"Updating Progress Bar");
    }
        break;
```

Thanks in Advance ...

Comment: is the "val" is float value?Have you put any breakpoint on this method?

Comment: No Madhumitha :) yeah val is an float value

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8803189/setprogress-is-no-longer-updating-uiprogressview-since-ios-5